# How to use net/xhr.getRequestCount()

Tags: firefox-addon-sdk

The documentation for [the `net/xhr` module](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/net_xhr) includes a method called [`getRequestCount()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/net_xhr#getRequestCount%28%29) supposed to

> Return[s] the number of XMLHttpRequest objects that are alive (i.e., currently active or about to be).

Both calling

```
const xhr = require("sdk/net/xhr");
var x = new xhr.XMLHttpRequest();
x.getRequestCount();
```

and

```
xhr.getRequestCount();
```

failed with a `TypeError`. In the debugger, you see that neither `XMLHttpRequest` nor its prototype have such function. (jpm version 1.0.5)

**How** are you supposed **to use it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this function was removed quite a while back(https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/rev/b57750ca97bf from 2013) and nobody remembered to update the documentation.

So in short: you're **not** supposed **to use it**.